# Downloading a file in Ruby, from a site that generates a download link?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a Ruby script that would download an image file from a website, which does not have an image on it initially. The way this site works normally is that when you access the site, the site waits for about a second while it generates the link to download the image. After that's done, the browser presents the user with a download window to actually download the image. At no point is the image presented on the site itself, the site always says "Please wait", or "your image is ready to download".

How can I write a quick and dirty ruby script to download these image file links to the user's desktop?

Comment: Based on the little you told us, odds are really good that the site uses dynamic HTML, with JavaScript doing the actual presentation of the download window. The only way to tap into that is to use something from the [Watir](http://watir.com) project.

Answer (score 1):

Use Watir and nokogiri

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'nokogiri'

$browser = Watir::Browser.new
$browser.goto "google.com"

$page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)

image = []
image = $page_html.css("img#hplogo").map{|link| link['src']}[0]

image_src = "https://www.google.com" + image

File.open("/home/user/Desktop/image.png", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write open(image_src).read
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the gem [mechanize](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize) is a popular way of automating interaction with websites.